# How do I resolve Cannot use 'Object' as class name as it is reserved in C:\projectfolder\ckphp-demo\cake\libs\object.php on line 33

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

In working on a new cakephp application I get the error message Cannot use 'Object' as class name as it is reserved in C:\projectfolder\ckphp-demo\cake\libs\object.php on line 33.

The project is a legacy web application using cakePHP 1.3.17 with php version PHP 7.4.28 on developement server. see below code for object.php

line 33 is where class Object { starts

```
<?php
/**
 * Object class, allowing __construct and __destruct in PHP4.
 *
 * Also includes methods for logging and the special method RequestAction,
 * to call other Controllers' Actions from anywhere.
 *
 * PHP versions 4 and 5
 *
 * CakePHP(tm) : Rapid Development Framework (http://cakephp.org)
 * Copyright 2005-2012, Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (http://cakefoundation.org)
 *
 * Licensed under The MIT License
 * Redistributions of files must retain the above copyright notice.
 *
 * @copyright     Copyright 2005-2012, Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (http://cakefoundation.org)
 * @link          http://cakephp.org CakePHP(tm) Project
 * @package       cake
 * @subpackage    cake.cake.libs
 * @since         CakePHP(tm) v 0.2.9
 * @license       MIT License (http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php)
 */

/**
 * Object class, allowing __construct and __destruct in PHP4.
 *
 * Also includes methods for logging and the special method RequestAction,
 * to call other Controllers' Actions from anywhere.
 *
 * @package cake
 * @subpackage cake.cake.libs
 */
class Object {

/**
 * A hack to support __construct() on PHP 4
 * Hint: descendant classes have no PHP4 class_name() constructors,
 * so this constructor gets called first and calls the top-layer __construct()
 * which (if present) should call parent::__construct()
 *
 * @return Object
 */
    function Object() {
        $args = func_get_args();
        if (method_exists($this, '__destruct')) {
            register_shutdown_function (array(&$this, '__destruct'));
        }
        call_user_func_array(array(&$this, '__construct'), $args);
    }

/**
 * Class constructor, overridden in descendant classes.
 */
    function __construct() {
    }

/**
 * Object-to-string conversion.
 * Each class can override this method as necessary.
 *
 * @return string The name of this class
 * @access public
 */
    function toString() {
        $class = get_class($this);
        return $class;
    }

/**
 * Calls a controller's method from any location. Can be used to connect controllers together
 * or tie plugins into a main application. requestAction can be used to return rendered views
 * or fetch the return value from controller actions.
 *
 * @param mixed $url String or array-based url.
 * @param array $extra if array includes the key "return" it sets the AutoRender to true.
 * @return mixed Boolean true or false on success/failure, or contents
 *    of rendered action if 'return' is set in $extra.
 * @access public
 */
    function requestAction($url, $extra = array()) {
        if (empty($url)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!class_exists('dispatcher')) {
            require CAKE . 'dispatcher.php';
        }
        if (in_array('return', $extra, true)) {
            $extra = array_merge($extra, array('return' => 0, 'autoRender' => 1));
        }
        if (is_array($url) && !isset($extra['url'])) {
            $extra['url'] = array();
        }
        $params = array_merge(array('autoRender' => 0, 'return' => 1, 'bare' => 1, 'requested' => 1), $extra);
        $dispatcher = new Dispatcher;
        return $dispatcher->dispatch($url, $params);
    }

/**
 * Calls a method on this object with the given parameters. Provides an OO wrapper
 * for `call_user_func_array`
 *
 * @param string $method  Name of the method to call
 * @param array $params  Parameter list to use when calling $method
 * @return mixed  Returns the result of the method call
 * @access public
 */
    function dispatchMethod($method, $params = array()) {
        switch (count($params)) {
            case 0:
                return $this->{$method}();
            case 1:
                return $this->{$method}($params[0]);
            case 2:
                return $this->{$method}($params[0], $params[1]);
            case 3:
                return $this->{$method}($params[0], $params[1], $params[2]);
            case 4:
                return $this->{$method}($params[0], $params[1], $params[2], $params[3]);
            case 5:
                return $this->{$method}($params[0], $params[1], $params[2], $params[3], $params[4]);
            default:
                return call_user_func_array(array(&$this, $method), $params);
            break;
        }
    }

/**
 * Stop execution of the current script.  Wraps exit() making 
 * testing easier.
 *
 * @param $status see http://php.net/exit for values
 * @return void
 * @access public
 */
    function _stop($status = 0) {
        exit($status);
    }

/**
 * Convience method to write a message to CakeLog.  See CakeLog::write()
 * for more information on writing to logs.
 *
 * @param string $msg Log message
 * @param integer $type Error type constant. Defined in app/config/core.php.
 * @return boolean Success of log write
 * @access public
 */
    function log($msg, $type = LOG_ERROR) {
        if (!class_exists('CakeLog')) {
            require LIBS . 'cake_log.php';
        }
        if (!is_string($msg)) {
            $msg = print_r($msg, true);
        }
        return CakeLog::write($type, $msg);
    }

/**
 * Allows setting of multiple properties of the object in a single line of code.  Will only set 
 * properties that are part of a class declaration.
 *
 * @param array $properties An associative array containing properties and corresponding values.
 * @return void
 * @access protected
 */
    function _set($properties = array()) {
        if (is_array($properties) && !empty($properties)) {
            $vars = get_object_vars($this);
            foreach ($properties as $key => $val) {
                if (array_key_exists($key, $vars)) {
                    $this->{$key} = $val;
                }
            }
        }
    }

/**
 * Used to report user friendly errors.
 * If there is a file app/error.php or app/app_error.php this file will be loaded
 * error.php is the AppError class it should extend ErrorHandler class.
 *
 * @param string $method Method to be called in the error class (AppError or ErrorHandler classes)
 * @param array $messages Message that is to be displayed by the error class
 * @return error message
 * @access public
 */
    function cakeError($method, $messages = array()) {
        if (!class_exists('ErrorHandler')) {
            App::import('Core', 'Error');

            if (file_exists(APP . 'error.php')) {
                include_once (APP . 'error.php');
            } elseif (file_exists(APP . 'app_error.php')) {
                include_once (APP . 'app_error.php');
            }
        }

        if (class_exists('AppError')) {
            $error = new AppError($method, $messages);
        } else {
            $error = new ErrorHandler($method, $messages);
        }
        return $error;
    }

/**
 * Checks for a persistent class file, if found file is opened and true returned
 * If file is not found a file is created and false returned
 * If used in other locations of the model you should choose a unique name for the persistent file
 * There are many uses for this method, see manual for examples
 *
 * @param string $name name of the class to persist
 * @param string $object the object to persist
 * @return boolean Success
 * @access protected
 * @todo add examples to manual
 */
    function _persist($name, $return = null, &$object, $type = null) {
        $file = CACHE . 'persistent' . DS . strtolower($name) . '.php';
        if ($return === null) {
            if (!file_exists($file)) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }

        if (!file_exists($file)) {
            $this->_savePersistent($name, $object);
            return false;
        } else {
            $this->__openPersistent($name, $type);
            return true;
        }
    }

/**
 * You should choose a unique name for the persistent file
 *
 * There are many uses for this method, see manual for examples
 *
 * @param string $name name used for object to cache
 * @param object $object the object to persist
 * @return boolean true on save, throws error if file can not be created
 * @access protected
 */
    function _savePersistent($name, &$object) {
        $file = 'persistent' . DS . strtolower($name) . '.php';
        $objectArray = array(&$object);
        $data = str_replace('\\', '\\\\', serialize($objectArray));
        $data = '<?php $' . $name . ' = \'' . str_replace('\'', '\\\'', $data) . '\' ?>';
        $duration = '+999 days';
        if (Configure::read() >= 1) {
            $duration = '+10 seconds';
        }
        cache($file, $data, $duration);
    }

/**
 * Open the persistent class file for reading
 * Used by Object::_persist()
 *
 * @param string $name Name of persisted class
 * @param string $type Type of persistance (e.g: registry)
 * @return void
 * @access private
 */
    function __openPersistent($name, $type = null) {
        $file = CACHE . 'persistent' . DS . strtolower($name) . '.php';
        include($file);

        switch ($type) {
            case 'registry':
                $vars = unserialize(${$name});
                foreach ($vars['0'] as $key => $value) {
                    if (strpos($key, '_behavior') !== false) {
                        App::import('Behavior', Inflector::classify(substr($key, 0, -9)));
                    } else {
                        App::import('Model', Inflector::camelize($key));
                    }
                    unset ($value);
                }
                unset($vars);
                $vars = unserialize(${$name});
                foreach ($vars['0'] as $key => $value) {
                    ClassRegistry::addObject($key, $value);
                    unset ($value);
                }
                unset($vars);
            break;
            default:
                $vars = unserialize(${$name});
                $this->{$name} = $vars['0'];
                unset($vars);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest not using `Object` as a class name...alter it. Looks like you're trying to use a product designed for PHP4/5 (and written in 2012 or thereabouts) on PHP7...a lot has changed in between. In fact, probably just better to upgrade your cake version - no doubt you'll get better features, security updates, bug fixes, and compatibility with supported PHP versions.

Comment: CakePHP 1.3 is not compatible out of the box with PHP 7. I managed to get it working once as a stopgap measure, but can't remember the details. It wasn't pretty.