# How do I solve Cake is NOT able to connect to the database on IIS Server running CakePHP 1.3.17

Tags: php, mysql, iis, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have setup the CakePHP framework version 1.3.17 on IIS server precisely IIS version 10.0.19041.1
all is well, as i can see the index.php page, however it is not able to connect to a MYSQL 8 database, see  database.php configuration settings. How do i check to see what the actual error is and also how do I resolve the connection issue

```
<?php
/**
 * This is core configuration file.
 *
 * Use it to configure core behaviour ofCake.
 *
 * PHP versions 4 and 5
 *
 * CakePHP(tm) : Rapid Development Framework (http://cakephp.org)
 * Copyright 2005-2012, Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (http://cakefoundation.org)
 *
 * Licensed under The MIT License
 * Redistributions of files must retain the above copyright notice.
 *
 * @copyright     Copyright 2005-2012, Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (http://cakefoundation.org)
 * @link          http://cakephp.org CakePHP(tm) Project
 * @package       cake
 * @subpackage    cake.app.config
 * @since         CakePHP(tm) v 0.2.9
 * @license       MIT License (http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php)
 */
/**
 * In this file you set up your database connection details.
 *
 * @package       cake
 * @subpackage    cake.config
 */
/**
 * Database configuration class.
 * You can specify multiple configurations for production, development and testing.
 *
 * driver => The name of a supported driver; valid options are as follows:
 *      mysql       - MySQL 4 & 5,
 *      mysqli      - MySQL 4 & 5 Improved Interface (PHP5 only),
 *      sqlite      - SQLite (PHP5 only),
 *      postgres    - PostgreSQL 7 and higher,
 *      mssql       - Microsoft SQL Server 2000 and higher,
 *      db2         - IBM DB2, Cloudscape, and Apache Derby (http://php.net/ibm-db2)
 *      oracle      - Oracle 8 and higher
 *      firebird    - Firebird/Interbase
 *      sybase      - Sybase ASE
 *      adodb-[drivername]  - ADOdb interface wrapper (see below),
 *      odbc        - ODBC DBO driver
 *
 * You can add custom database drivers (or override existing drivers) by adding the
 * appropriate file to app/models/datasources/dbo.  Drivers should be named 'dbo_x.php',
 * where 'x' is the name of the database.
 *
 * persistent => true / false
 * Determines whether or not the database should use a persistent connection
 *
 * connect =>
 * ADOdb set the connect to one of these
 *  (http://phplens.com/adodb/supported.databases.html) and
 *  append it '|p' for persistent connection. (mssql|p for example, or just mssql for not persistent)
 * For all other databases, this setting is deprecated.
 *
 * host =>
 * the host you connect to the database.  To add a socket or port number, use 'port' => #
 *
 * prefix =>
 * Uses the given prefix for all the tables in this database.  This setting can be overridden
 * on a per-table basis with the Model::$tablePrefix property.
 *
 * schema =>
 * For Postgres and DB2, specifies which schema you would like to use the tables in. Postgres defaults to
 * 'public', DB2 defaults to empty.
 *
 * encoding =>
 * For MySQL, MySQLi, Postgres and DB2, specifies the character encoding to use when connecting to the
 * database.  Uses database default.
 *
 */
class DATABASE_CONFIG {

    var $default = array(
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'port' => '3306',
        'login' => 'username',
        'password' => 'mypassword',
        'database' => 'mydatabasename',
        'prefix' => '',
        'cacheMetadata' => false,
        'encoding' => 'utf8'
    );
}
```

Here's a print screen of what is displayed, when the application is accessed on a browser via http://localhost

[image]

Comment: What error / indication are you getting currently, if it's not a detailed error message?

Comment: no specific error message is displayed when i accesss cakephp via url on a browser, just the message cake is not able to connect to the database,highlighed in yellow right after the message your database configuration file is present highlighted in green

Comment: Anything in the PHP error log (I'm assuming you've got error logging configured in your PHP setup)

Comment: on php error logs i get [04-Aug-2022 14:12:51] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\Program Files\PHP\v5.2\ext\php_pdo_mssql.dll' - The specified module could not be found.  the application is configured to use php 5.2 on IIS

Comment: Seems that PDO is missing from the install then. Which would likely explain why you can't access the database. Why are you using such a decrepit version of PHP though? You [asked about this ancient cakePHP install yesterday too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73223215/how-do-i-resolve-cannot-use-object-as-class-name-as-it-is-reserved-in-c-proje) after encountering compatibility problems. If it were me, I'd stop flogging the dead horse.

Comment: Yes i have changed PHP version to 5.6 which has the php_pdo_mysql.dll but im still getting the message cannot connect to database

Comment: And is there any different error in the log after that?

Comment: P.S. PHP 5.6 is still ancient and unsupported, too.

Comment: but for cakephp 1.3.17 it should still be valid

Comment: Perhaps, I don't know personally. But whether PDO was installed or not is a different issue. And you should never run unsupported software, it's a big security risk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running CakePHP 1.3.17 on IIS server precisely IIS version 10.0.19041.1 requires;

- PHP version 5.6.x. It will not work with PHP 7 and above
- MySQL version 5.6. It will not connect to any MySQL version higher than 5.6.

I had to install XAMPP with MYSQL 5.6 and configure it to use port 3307 because I had another instance of MYSQL 8.0 running on port 3306 which CAKEPHP v1.3.17 could not connect to.

In database.php, see code used in the database_config class used

```
var $default = array(
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'port' => '3307',
    'login' => 'myappusername',
    'password' => 'mypassword',
    'database' => 'myapp_db',
    'prefix' => '',
    //'encoding' => 'utf8',
);
```

Comment: If you can mark your answer, it will lead more people in the right direction.